# Ubuntu Phone - both SIM cards always active?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone, bq

I just got my Aquaris E4.5. Is there a way how to switch off just one of the SIM cards? Sometimes I don't want/need one SIM card to be reachable. And I hope to reduce the energy consumption a little bit.

I could switch off the phone and the switch on again and enter just one PIN and ignore the other one but perhaps there is a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot.  But you can unplug the SIM card when you don't need it and re-insert it when you do...

(Hardware solution to a software problem)

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**